# jQuery.Ajax make ie9 to reload it's plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

It really shocked me!

jQuery.Ajax works great in ie8, but when i use ie9, i found that every time when i use send a jquery ajax call, the ie9 will reload all of it's plugins.(I mean the plugins registered with ie9, such as a web-bank plugin and so on.)

I never found this until there is a very big plugin in my customer's ie9, that's a web-bank plugin, it's important, and cound not be set down.

This big plugin need about 3 second to load itself when ie9 is starting. But I don't know how and why, every time I send a jquery ajax call, the ie9 will reload all of it's plugins. So it means every call will delay about 3 seconds!

How to fix it? 
I try at least 3 machines with ie9(lastest version), it's the same.
I am very sure ie9 is reloading it's plugin, because when i shut down the big plugin, the ajax call will finished very soon.

yours,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

What's your ajax call, give us some code.

I am currently using the following code on my website with no problems

```
$.post("script.php",$("#form").serialize());
```

Comment: jQuery.ajax({ 
       url: "/KPIGetData/AssessSavingData.aspx?InputType1&rand=dt,
    type: "GET",  just like this, standard jquery ajax.  You don't found that perhaps you have not a BIG ie9 plugin to show the delaying.